Python: Converting Coordinates for Mouse Movement Across Different Screen Resolutions
I'm currently working on a project where I need to move the mouse cursor to specific coordinates on the screen. To ensure that the mouse movement works across different screen resolutions, I've implemented a function to convert the coordinates before passing them to the 'mouse_move' function.
Here are the functions I'm using:
from pyautogui import *
from win32api import SetCursorPos


def convert_cords(x, y):
    w, h = size()
    original_res = (1360, 768)
    ratio_x = w / original_res[0]
    ratio_y = h / original_res[1]
    new_x = round(x * ratio_x)
    new_y = round(y * ratio_y)
    return (new_x, new_y)

def mouse_move(x, y):
    new_x, new_y = convert_cords(x, y)
    SetCursorPos((new_x, new_y))


The 'convert_cords' function takes the original coordinates (x, y) and scales them based on the ratio of the current screen resolution to the original resolution (1360, 768). The 'mouse_move' function then uses these converted coordinates to move the mouse cursor.
However, when I test the code on a screen resolution of 1920x1080, I notice that the mouse cursor doesn't land exactly where I expect it to. It seems to be off by a few pixels.
I'm wondering if there's a flaw in my approach or if someone has encountered a similar issue and found a solution. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

There is no flaw (as far as I can see) in the piece of code you've shown, and from the little we know. It is just proportionality. Flaw is probably in the real world you are dealing with, about which you say nothing: changing screen resolution doesn't left every thing exactly were it was, and coordinates are not exactly proportional to screen resolution

I am completely speculating here. But let's say that what you are trying to click on is a button in a browser. And that every positioning in that webpage is done in wh or % (so is independent of screen resolution). Which is a strong hypothesis. Many sites use more raw positioning (in pixels, cm, ...). But even under this hypothesis, the exact position of elements that are not absolutely positioned (whose position depends on the size of the previous one) would vary if font size isn't exactly the same (and font size isn't always the same. Anybody who has already made a website with

everything expressed in wv, wh and then played with the zoom button can tel you that you can't make one that is completely agnostic to resolution).

But even assuming so that not only the interface use only positioning proportional to the window size, and that it works perfectly, there is still variations. To start with, window size is not the screen size. If the window borders are in pixels (which is usually the case), then window size is screen size minus a few pixels. And here goes your proportionality hypothesis.

Plus the fact that you can't treat X and Y as they were exactly independent. There are always some relation between both, because there is always something that must be squared, or have a given ratio (The O of this font is supposed to be a circle, not an ellipse. This image must preserve its aspect ratio, etc). And since screen resolutions are not all exactly proportional to 4:3, or 16:9 (or 16:10 — because it is also better if sizes are multiple of 16), that means that not all screen resolutions, even under the almost impossible "purely linear hypothesis"

have the same aspect ratio. And are therefore either forced to squeeze a bit images (and most lib won't ever do that), or to change a bit the positioning of elements

The two examples resultion you have mentioned for example: 1920x1080 is exactly 16/9 = 1.777777... But 1360/768 isn't. It is 1.77083...  1360×765 would have been a perfect 16/9 resolution. But 765 is a loosy size for many things. Nobody working on graphic cards, image codec, etc, would want an odd resolution. 768 is a multiple of 256 and is only 3 more. That is an excellent compromise. But that ruins your "perfect proportionality" ideal (even if it weren't anyway almost impossible because of the other mentioned reasons)
